# How to wordpress multi site

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I am setting up a wordpress for a friend, how do I make it so I can control both websites at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to explain it all here is a bit beyond the scope. Perhaps it is best to start here, and then you can ask detailed questions if you encounter problems:https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network

Comment: I cannot access the site, my school blocked that site.

Comment: do you have access to the wordpress.org site? https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at no.reply.nate.sturtz@gmail.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1c Server at sturtz.ml Port 443

Comment: When I followed it this is what I got

Comment: What did you try so far, did you deactivate all plugins? 

A similar problem has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216881/how-do-i-fix-an-internal-server-error-on-a-wordpress-multisite-network)

Comment: I had to reinstall, completely, I could not access anything at all

Comment: I have a backup of my database in SQL, how do I put just the posts back into my site?